# Google sheets formula to count total rows in a range if in that range the date in column a is equal to X

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m in Google Sheets and I imported data collected all last year. In column a I have a time stamp with the date and time. In column b I have a dollar amount. That’s in a sheet, for this example, is called Sheet A.

OLD——————————-

Now, I have a Sheet B where I have the days of 2022 going down. So row 2 has 1/1/2022 and row 3 has 1/2/2022, and so on and so on.

OLD——————————-

NEW——————————-

Sheet b has an interesting format, please check the sample sheet link below to see the format.

NEW——————————-

In sheet b, next to each of the dates I have 2 columns, one for count and one for dollar amount. I would like it so that in the count column, it counts each row instance in sheet a that matches the date next to it in one column, and then counts the total dollar amount in another column.

So in sheet b, row one column a is 1/1/2022, column b is the count, and column c is the total dollar amount.

Please help me, I can not figure this out.

I’ve tried a lot, nothing has worked. I’m not formatting the formulas correctly I assume.

Here is the sheet I created for the example, if you could please use it to show me what to do. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ZYOKXS6YO66qslyNGP-V2eWyx40h-Lc5jaobmFRjaY/edit

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

In cell `'Sheet3'!C2`, use `vlookup()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      to_pure_number(A1) + A2:A - 1, 
      query( 
        { datevalue('Sheet A'!A2:A), 'Sheet A'!B2:C }, 
        "select Col1, count(Col1), sum(Col2) group by Col1", 0 
      ), 
      { 2, 3 }, false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: That worked on my test sheet, now I need to see if it works on my actual sheet. My real Sheet is formatted slightly different, but it should be the same. If it doesn’t work I’ll update my sample sheet. Thank you so much.

Comment: I updated my sheet b with the exact format of the sheet I’m working with. Can you please help me modify your code to work for that format? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another option, maybe more automatized but you should check if it's useful.

By setting a first cell with a day in that month (in my case K1) you'll have the chart with those days, days of week, count and totals:

```
=QUERY('Sheet A'!A2:B,"Select A,dayOfweek(A),Count(A),Sum(B) 
where A is not null AND MONTH(A) = "&MONTH(K1)-1&" 
group by A 
label A 'date', dayOfweek(A) 'deposit day', Count(A) '# of checks', Sum(B) '$ dollars rounded' 
format dayOfweek(A) 'dddd' ")
```

[image]